How to select which index an item is placed at when using Angular CDK Drag and Drop?
I have a cdkDropListGroup with two cdkDropList's. Both have cdkDropListSortingDisabled set to false and you are only supposed to move items from one drop list to another - at which they should be placed at certain index, based on the orderWeight property of the item.
How do I select which index an item is going to be placed at when it enters the droplist?
I already have a functionality that moves the item from one droplist to another to specific index (using cdkDropListDropped and transferArrayItem), but that only happens after the item is dropped. When entering the new droplist the item is placed based on the "enter" mouse position as seen on the image bellow.
drop animation

A cdkDropList it's only a "way to show" two arrays. When you drop, you change the two arrays (using the function transferArrayItem or another one), then Angular show the result. In the argument of the function drop you have event.previousContainer.data, event.container.data, event.previousIndex and event.currentIndex,

This does not answer my question and is not entirely correct. Please read what I wrote and what I already have (check the provided image).The cdkDropList and cdkDrag directives provide the drag and drop functionality. With the transferArrayItem you just move an item from one drop list to another. I need to somehow override where the cdk-drag-placeholder is created in the droplist on "mouse enter".
